# What library to use for generating PDF

Tags: pdf-generation

What should I use for generating PDF in Java. It has to be free.

Comment: It's swing GUI. Some kind of forms and tables.

Comment: Why do I have those negative votes? I've just normally asked. I need to generate PDF from java application and woul like to know what library to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html) or [iText](http://itextpdf.com/). The iText library is LGPL license until version 2.1.7 AFAIK.

Comment: I will look at the iText. Tkanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using LaTeX? You can generate the .tex using java, then you can compile it to produce a PDF using command line
http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/basics-of-latex-from-the-command-line/

Comment: But I don't know LaTeX. Does it have java API?

Comment: it's no necessary an API, because is a code externally compiled. I really advice you to use it. At work we produce PDF using an awful library (and we pay it!): we have to write xml to format the page and then the library produces the PDF. LaTeX is free and you can do ALL YOU WANT! :D